# Как сделать одну сторону View кривой волной?

Tags: ios, swift, view, design

Подскажите пожалуйста как задать одной стороне view кривую сторону например нижнюю? Очень буду благодарен за ссылку например урока.Например я хочу сделать вот такую форму.Картинка прилагается.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно использовать `UIBezierPath` и рисовать в своем UIView переопределив метод `draw(_ rect: CGRect)`.

Как работать с UIBezierPath описано тут, думаю сообразишь как сделать именно нужный тебе эффект:
https://www.appcoda.com/bezier-paths-introduction/